# 実機でのテストでAuthorizationStatus.NotDeterminedを再現するには？(iOS8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, ios8

iOS8でカメラを使ったアプリの開発をしているおり、実機でのテストが不可欠な状況です。

起動時にAVAuthorizationStatusを調べて、その対応を行うようにしているのですが、
一度、実機でテストを行ってしまうと、
その後、アプリアイコンを長押しして、アプリを削除しても、
アプリにひも付けられたAuthorizedStatusが残っているようで、
AVAuthorizedStatus.NotDetermind
の状態をテストすることができません。

シミュレーターなら、リセットすると、AuthorizedStatusがクリアされるようですが、
テストとは言え、使用する実機は実生活で使用しているものでもあり、その度に
実機をクリアするのは、実質的に無理な状況です。

なにかよい解決方法はありますでしょうか？
現在、Swiftを利用していますが、Objective-Cでも構いません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 設定>一般>リセット>位置情報とプライバシーをリセット ではダメですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2つ方法があります。

1つ目はアプリのバンドル名を変えてしまうことです。別アプリとして認識させてしまえば、再度`NotDetermind`をテストできます。

よりスマートな方法として、「設定」の「一般」＞「リセット」＞「位置情報とプライバシーをリセット」で、権限のみリセットすることができます。ただし個別のアプリを指定できず、全てのアプリの情報がクリアされてしまう欠点があります。

Comment: h2so5さん、quesera2さん、ありがとうございます。アプリのバンドル名を変える方法は、なんとなく可能性があるとは思っていましたが、このために名前をたくさん用意するのも気が引けました。「位置情報とプライバシーのリセット」は、よりよい方法だと思いますが、すべてのアプリについてリセットされてしまうのが、少なからぬ欠点と思います。まずは、これでテストしていきますが、もし、他によい方法があれば、ご教示いただければと思います。引き続きよろしくお願いいたします。